# how to configure flume for tibco JMS ssl

Tags: ssl, jms, flume, tibco-ems

I am using the tibco JMS as source for the flume and wondering how to enable SSL for this. In documentation I see `ssl` should set to `true` for other type of sources. I didn't see this `ssl` property for JMS. Please help me to configure JMS source to use `ssl`

```
agent.sources.mySrc.type = jms
agent.sources.mySrc.initialContextFactory = com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
agent.sources.mySrc.providerURL = tibjmsnaming://mysever:port
agent.sources.mySrc.destinationName = <queuename>
agent.sources.mySrc.destinationType = queue
agent.sources.mySrc.batchSize=50
agent.sources.mySrc.connectionFactory = QueueConnectionFactory
agent.sources.mySrc.userName=user
agent.sources.mySrc.passwordFile=/opt/flume/conf/password.txt
agent.sources.mySrc.converter.type=org.apache.flume.source.jms.ELFJMSMessageEventUUIDConverter$Builder

agent.sources.mySrc.selector.type = multiplexing
agent.sources.mySrc.selector.header=zone
```

This is my JMS and wondering is there any properties like below for JMS source

```
# SSL properties for Thrift source s1 
a1.sources.r1.ssl=true
a1.sources.r1.keystore=<path/to/keystore>
a1.sources.r1.keystore-password=<keystore password>
a1.sources.r1.keystore-type=<keystore type>
```

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Flume JMS Source doesn't have this feature. Flume Avro source has this.

https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/AvroSource.java

You can refer the above class and write a custom JMS source similar to above class.